# System Argument Error from direct file location and TextBox1

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am creating a project which will convert xls to xlsx, doc to docx and ppt to pptx using Spire libraries.

I am browsing files and then saving the files complete location to TextBox1.text.
I get the error "System.ArgumentException 'The directory (then path) name is invalid' even if a single file is in TextBox1, multiple files in TextBox1 or even if I provide direct path. Unable to understand what's wrong.

```
private void BTNConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(textBox1.Text);
            fsw.Created += (s, a) => {
                if (!a.FullPath.EndsWith(".xls")) { return; }
                var newName = a.FullPath.Remove(a.FullPath.Length - 3) + "xlsx";
                var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                var book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(a.FullPath);
                book.SaveAs(newName, XlFileFormat.xlExcel12);
                xlApp.Quit();
            };


            //ProgressBar
           // backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
           // backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

            //Create a Workbook instance
            //Spire.Xls.Workbook workbook = new Spire.Xls.Workbook();
            //Load an XLS file
            //workbook.LoadFromFile(textBox1.Text);
            //Convert the file to XLSX format
            //workbook.SaveToFile(@"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Converted Files\test.xlsx", Spire.Xls.ExcelVersion.Version2016);
```

Comment: Hi welcome to the forum. The error message indicates that whatever is in `textBox1.Text` is an invalid directory or file path. You mention `TextBox1` in your comment, did you mean `textBox1`? I would suggest that you copy `textBox1.Text` to an intermediate variable so that you can debug the issue. Also place a `try... catch` block around the code to capture more exception information in debug mode.

Comment: Hi @ChrisBD, Thank you for warm welcome. Yes I used Textbox1.Text. It is having the location C:\Users\Text\text.xls file. Even if I remove TextBox1 from 'var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(textBox1.Text);' and I provide direct path, it will still give me same error.

Comment: Are you asking the FileSystemWatcher to look for a file instead of a folder? What happens if you put just the folder name in the textbox? IE _C:\Users\Text_

Comment: Yes. I am trying the FileSystemWatcher to read all files from TextBox1.text. When I put direct path and click on convert button, its just giving me message box dialog box. Nothing more happening.

Comment: Please post a `TextBox1.Text` value that triggers the exception. Also do you know which line triggers the exception?

Comment: Dialogbox is saving text into TextBox1.Text
'private void BTNBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.InitialDirectory = @"\Desktop";
dialog.Title = "Browse old office files";
dialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls)|*.xls|Word Files(*.doc)|*.doc|PowerPoint Files(*.ppt)|*.ppt";
dialog.DefaultExt = ".xls";
dialog.Multiselect = true;
var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
foreach (string file in dialog.FileNames)
{textBox1.AppendText(file + Environment.NewLine);
 }           
}'

Comment: Line which triggers the exception
'var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(textBox1.Text);'

Comment: I am just curious if there is anyway we can get the entire path of all files from TextBox1.Text to FileSystemWatcher. Currently, FileSystemWatcher is just grabbing directory and that's why I guess its giving me illegal characters error because Textbox1.text has complete path with filename.xls. When I give just directory, it doesn't generate any error.